Latest Tree-based models
What are the latest Tree-based models that are used in machine learning? Tell the new models except the old ones such as the Decision tree, Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, LightGBM, XGBoost, and CatBoost.

Just a cursory search on arxiv, graph tree based deep nn. Looks interesting: https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.12802
